# How to get the combinations of several sub vector?

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to have the combinations of several sub vectors. I tried to do it with two `for` loops but I think I need recursion. The main problem is that I'm working with a vector of vectors so most of the answers on the internet do not work with my case.

What I have is a vector with several sub vectors, something like that :

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> x = {{{0,0},{1,1}},{{2,2},{3,3}},{{4,4},{5,5}}}
```

The output that I expect is a vector with all the possible combinations like this:

```
{{{0,0},{2,2},{4,4}},{{0,0},{2,2},{5,5}},{{0,0},{3,3},{4,4}},{{0,0},{3,3},{5,5}},...}
```

Here are all the output that i need for the exemple above : 
`{{0,0},{2,2},{4,4}} {{0,0},{2,2},{5,5}} {{0,0},{3,3},{4,4}} {{0,0},{3,3},{5,5}} 
{{1,1},{2,2},{4,4}} {{1,1},{2,2},{5,5}} {{1,1},{3,3},{4,4}} {{1,1},{3,3},{5,5}}`

If the size of my vector is 3 and the size of my sub vector is also 3 like so : `{{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}},{{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}},{{6,6},{7,7},{8,8}}}`

The output has to be :

```
{{0,0},{3,3},{6,6}} , {{0,0},{3,3},{7,7}} , {{0,0},{3,3},{8,8}} ,  {{0,0},{4,4},{6,6}} , {{0,0},{4,4},{7,7}} , {{0,0},{4,4},{8,8}} ...
```

The same goes for any size of my vector/sub vector

Comment: You seem to expect 3 vectors, but have only declared 2.

Comment: i don't understand what you meant by that. My "x" vector is just an exemple. All i want is a new vector with all the combinations possible (like shown above).Creating a new vector is not the problem but fill it with the right data dynamically is

Comment: The result is `{x[0][0],x[1][0],x[2][0]} {x[0][0],x[1][0],x[2][1]} {x[0][0],x[1][1],x[2][0]} {x[0][0],x[1][1],x[2][1]} 
{x[0][1],x[1][0],x[2][0]} {x[0][1],x[1][0],x[2][1]} {x[0][1],x[1][1],x[2][0]} {x[0][1],x[1][1],x[2][1]}`. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: @bolov yes sorry about that, i'll edit it.

Comment: `for(uint i{0}; i < x[0].size(); ++i) for(uint j{0}; j < x[1].size(); ++j) for(uint k{0}; k < x[2].size(); ++k) vec.push_back({x[0][i], x[1][j], x[2][k]});`

Comment: @ThomasSablik Thank you for your answer. The problem here is that my vector `x` is not always of size 3. In addition , the subs vector are not always in size 2 also. We can have something like that : 

 `{{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}},{{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}},{{},{},{}.}...}`

Comment: You could create a vector of idexes `v_i` beginning with {0, 0, 0, ...}. In a loop you push_back the elements `x[i][v_i]` and increment `v_i`. If `v_i` can't be incremented you break the loop

Comment: ok i'll try to do it like that , thank you

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Got busy. What I'm saying is the way your data is split seems to be in sets of 3, not sets of 2.

Comment: @Chipster it's ok , thomas sablik gave me the answer and I understood how he implemented it, thanks again for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector of indexes `vi` beginning with {0, 0, 0, ...}. In a loop you push_back the elements `x[i][vi[i]]` into a temp vector and increment `vi`.

You increment `vi` from back in a loop with: if `vi[i]` is larger than `x[i].size()` you increment `vi[i - 1]` ...

If `vi` can't be incremented you break the loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::size_t;
using std::vector;

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const vector<vector<vector<int>>> &vvec);
vector<vector<vector<int>>> combinations(const vector<vector<vector<int>>> &vvec);

int main() {
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> x = {{{0,0},{1,1}},{{2,2},{3,3}},{{4,4},{5,5}}};
    cout << combinations(x);
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const vector<vector<vector<int>>> &vvec) {
    bool first1 = true;
    for (const auto &v : vvec) {
        if (first1) first1 = false;
        else os << ' ';
        bool first2 = true;
        os << '{';
        for (const auto &el : v) {
            if (first2) first2 = false;
            else os << ',';
            os << '{' << el[0] << ',' << el[1] << '}';
        }
        os << '}';
    }
    return os;
}

vector<vector<vector<int>>> combinations(const vector<vector<vector<int>>> &x) {
    vector<size_t> vectorOfIndexes(x.size());
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> resultVector;
    bool finished = false;
    while (!finished) {
        vector<std::vector<int>> combination;
        for (size_t i{0}; i < vectorOfIndexes.size(); ++i) {
            combination.push_back(x[i][vectorOfIndexes[i]]);
        }
        resultVector.push_back(combination);
        for (size_t i {0}; i < vectorOfIndexes.size(); ++i) {
            ++vectorOfIndexes[vectorOfIndexes.size() - i - 1];
            if (vectorOfIndexes[vectorOfIndexes.size() - i - 1] >= x[x.size() - i - 1].size()) {
                vectorOfIndexes[vectorOfIndexes.size() - i - 1] = 0;
                if (i == vectorOfIndexes.size() - 1) finished = true;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultVector;
}
```

Input:

```
{{{0,0},{1,1}},{{2,2},{3,3}},{{4,4},{5,5}}}
```

Output:

```
{{0,0},{2,2},{4,4}} {{0,0},{2,2},{5,5}} {{0,0},{3,3},{4,4}} {{0,0},{3,3},{5,5}} {{1,1},{2,2},{4,4}} {{1,1},{2,2},{5,5}} {{1,1},{3,3},{4,4}} {{1,1},{3,3},{5,5}}
```

Input:

```
{{{0,0},{1,1},{2,2}},{{3,3},{4,4},{5,5}},{{6,6},{7,7},{8,8}},{{9,9},{10,10},{11,11}}}
```

Output:

```
{{0,0},{3,3},{6,6},{9,9}} {{0,0},{3,3},{6,6},{10,10}} {{0,0},{3,3},{6,6},{11,11}} {{0,0},{3,3},{7,7},{9,9}} {{0,0},{3,3},{7,7},{10,10}} {{0,0},{3,3},{7,7},{11,11}} {{0,0},{3,3},{8,8},{9,9}} {{0,0},{3,3},{8,8},{10,10}} {{0,0},{3,3},{8,8},{11,11}} {{0,0},{4,4},{6,6},{9,9}} {{0,0},{4,4},{6,6},{10,10}} {{0,0},{4,4},{6,6},{11,11}} {{0,0},{4,4},{7,7},{9,9}} {{0,0},{4,4},{7,7},{10,10}} {{0,0},{4,4},{7,7},{11,11}} {{0,0},{4,4},{8,8},{9,9}} {{0,0},{4,4},{8,8},{10,10}} {{0,0},{4,4},{8,8},{11,11}} {{0,0},{5,5},{6,6},{9,9}} {{0,0},{5,5},{6,6},{10,10}} {{0,0},{5,5},{6,6},{11,11}} {{0,0},{5,5},{7,7},{9,9}} {{0,0},{5,5},{7,7},{10,10}} {{0,0},{5,5},{7,7},{11,11}} {{0,0},{5,5},{8,8},{9,9}} {{0,0},{5,5},{8,8},{10,10}} {{0,0},{5,5},{8,8},{11,11}} {{1,1},{3,3},{6,6},{9,9}} {{1,1},{3,3},{6,6},{10,10}} {{1,1},{3,3},{6,6},{11,11}} {{1,1},{3,3},{7,7},{9,9}} {{1,1},{3,3},{7,7},{10,10}} {{1,1},{3,3},{7,7},{11,11}} {{1,1},{3,3},{8,8},{9,9}} {{1,1},{3,3},{8,8},{10,10}} {{1,1},{3,3},{8,8},{11,11}} {{1,1},{4,4},{6,6},{9,9}} {{1,1},{4,4},{6,6},{10,10}} {{1,1},{4,4},{6,6},{11,11}} {{1,1},{4,4},{7,7},{9,9}} {{1,1},{4,4},{7,7},{10,10}} {{1,1},{4,4},{7,7},{11,11}} {{1,1},{4,4},{8,8},{9,9}} {{1,1},{4,4},{8,8},{10,10}} {{1,1},{4,4},{8,8},{11,11}} {{1,1},{5,5},{6,6},{9,9}} {{1,1},{5,5},{6,6},{10,10}} {{1,1},{5,5},{6,6},{11,11}} {{1,1},{5,5},{7,7},{9,9}} {{1,1},{5,5},{7,7},{10,10}} {{1,1},{5,5},{7,7},{11,11}} {{1,1},{5,5},{8,8},{9,9}} {{1,1},{5,5},{8,8},{10,10}} {{1,1},{5,5},{8,8},{11,11}} {{2,2},{3,3},{6,6},{9,9}} {{2,2},{3,3},{6,6},{10,10}} {{2,2},{3,3},{6,6},{11,11}} {{2,2},{3,3},{7,7},{9,9}} {{2,2},{3,3},{7,7},{10,10}} {{2,2},{3,3},{7,7},{11,11}} {{2,2},{3,3},{8,8},{9,9}} {{2,2},{3,3},{8,8},{10,10}} {{2,2},{3,3},{8,8},{11,11}} {{2,2},{4,4},{6,6},{9,9}} {{2,2},{4,4},{6,6},{10,10}} {{2,2},{4,4},{6,6},{11,11}} {{2,2},{4,4},{7,7},{9,9}} {{2,2},{4,4},{7,7},{10,10}} {{2,2},{4,4},{7,7},{11,11}} {{2,2},{4,4},{8,8},{9,9}} {{2,2},{4,4},{8,8},{10,10}} {{2,2},{4,4},{8,8},{11,11}} {{2,2},{5,5},{6,6},{9,9}} {{2,2},{5,5},{6,6},{10,10}} {{2,2},{5,5},{6,6},{11,11}} {{2,2},{5,5},{7,7},{9,9}} {{2,2},{5,5},{7,7},{10,10}} {{2,2},{5,5},{7,7},{11,11}} {{2,2},{5,5},{8,8},{9,9}} {{2,2},{5,5},{8,8},{10,10}} {{2,2},{5,5},{8,8},{11,11}}
```